# Add Ubuntu official repository keys to Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnupg, apt

I'd like to compile Ubuntu source packages on Debian. I've added a relevant `deb-src` line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
liori:~% grep ubuntu /etc/apt/sources.list
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid universe
```

and updated the list of packages by `aptitude update`. How do I securely obtain and add the relevant Ubuntu GPG keys, so that my `apt` will be able to verify files downloaded Ubuntu repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Debian itself, the Ubuntu repository keys themselves are part of a package – namely, [ubuntu-keyring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/ubuntu-keyring). You can install it with `dpkg -i`.

It also exists in the Debian repository, although named [ubuntu-archive-keyring](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ubuntu-archive-keyring).

Comment: How do I securely obtain it? The page you linked is not encrypted, and this package is not in debian repositories.

Comment: Extract it from a signed Ubuntu `.iso`, or see the update.

Comment: OK, the package indeed contains the required keys, but for some reason I couldn't use them immediately. I had to manually `apt-key add` them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When trying to install a package it probably tells you which key it is missing. You can use the Key ID it provides to add a key to the APT keyring, using the `add-apt-key` command. 
See [Ubuntu man-page for add-apt-key](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/add-apt-key.8.html)

Comment: Note, I don't want to install packages, just download source packages. Also, no, it doesn't say which key it demands. All I get is a message: "The following packages cannot be authenticated! freeciv E: Some packages could not be authenticated" (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52886258/13156sfq34t/Terminal%20-%20%7E%20%28liori%40liori-pc%29_044.png).

Comment: As it seems to download the sources from the freeciv git repository either way, you could check them out yourself from there and build them. As I do not have a debian system at hand I can't reproduce the case, but otherwise you could try to import the ubuntu-keyring into your apt-keyring and see whether that is the only problem there.